# Rust function returning std::time::Instant

Tags: rust

I have a function that returns time elapsed.

I had originally tried

```
fn insert_test(Table: &mut HashMap<String,String>, items: &Vec<String>) -> std::time::Instant {
```

But the compiler errored on

```
^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Instant`, found `u128`
```

But the compiler tells me to use `u128` instead

But how would I know u128 ahead of time? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html itself does not explicitly state its of type `u128`

```
// inserts items onto the referenced datastruct and returns time elapsed
fn insert_test(Table: &mut HashMap<String,String>, items: &Vec<String>) -> u128 {
    let t0 = Instant::now();
    for i in items {
        Table.insert(i.to_string(), "blahblah".to_string());
    }
    let duration = t0.elapsed().as_millis();
    duration
}
```

[rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba89f8cc02abca909526ade0698861a8)

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html#method.as_millis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your instinct to return a time object rather than a raw number was a good one. However, time elapsed is better represented as a [`Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html) (time delta) rather than an [`Instant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html) (moment in time).

Instead of changing the return type I would remove the `as_millis` call. It works out nicely because [`elapsed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html#method.elapsed) returns a `Duration`, which is just what we want.

```
fn insert_test(Table: &mut HashMap<String, String>, items: &Vec<String>) -> std::time::Duration {
    let t0 = Instant::now();
    for i in items {
        Table.insert(i.to_string(), "blahblah".to_string());
    }
    t0.elapsed()
}
```